# Shifting fractions in c

Tags: c, binary, bit-shift

I have this code:

```
int a = 3, b = 2;
(a/b) << 3 ;
```

How would `a/b` be shifted? And how can i represent fractions in binary?

Comment: What do you mean with binary?...

Comment: @Deduplicator Zeros and ones

Comment: That comment is disingenious. Try it again with some details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(a/b) will not get shifted.
It will evaluate the expression (a/b) int/int probably an int, then it will be shifted.

```
(a/b) << 3
(3/2) << 3 //integer divided by an integer will gives you an integer, So you will get 1
(1) << 3 // 1 will get left shifted with 3 bits
8
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `3 / 2` is `1`, the answer is simply `8`, i.e. 1 × 2<sup>3</sup>.

Answer (score 2):

1) Integers and floating point are both "binary" representations.
   In this sense, one way to "represent fractions" is simple to use floating point.

2) One effective way to represent fractions with integers ... is to use a *pair* of integers: one for your numerator, the other for your divisor:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_%28mathematics%29

3) Yet a third alternative is to use fixed point integer arithmetic

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic